# Can photographs be taken in Istanbul as of August/September 2016?

Tags: safety, event-based-effects, photography, istanbul

I'd like to go visit Istanbul in one of the next weeks; I'm not scared by it (I mean, things can happen anywhere), just concerned about possible consequences of taking photos.

I've heard a few third-hand reports about police -- before the coup -- being a bit harsh on photographers. Is it still the same, or even worse than that? Perhaps it has never been like that and those reports has just being exaggerated? I can evaluate how much risk I am prepared to take if I can get access to current information about the police.

I'd obviously avoid sensitive targets (policemen, military personnel and buildings). But I like to take photos of common places, too, so while I'll probably take photos of famous buildings I could take shots of common houses, telephone boots, generic skyscraper...everything that can make a good shot. But then, I've heard (from a friend of a friend of a friend...) that you can get in trouble with police if they think you are shooting things that they think are not interesting and thus you are not supposed to take photos of.

Comment: You're still asking a question that involves opinion. We don't know what level counts as "safe" for you. Could you clarify either: What level of problems would make things "unsafe" *or* reword the question to ask about consequences of photographing without asking us to judge it as safe/unsafe.

Comment: What are you going to take photos of? It should be absolutely safe to take photos of Hague Sofia and Blue Mosque, for example. Or are you planning to take photos of police or military installations?

Comment: @GeorgeY.: I'd obviously avoid sensibles targets (policemen, military personnel and buildings). But I like to take photos of common places, too, so while I'll probably take photos of famous buildings I could take shots of common houses, telephone boots, generic skyscraper...everything that can make a good shot. But then, I've heard (from a friend of a friend of a friend...) that you can get in trouble with police if they think you are shoting things that they think are not interesting and thus you are not supposed to take photo of...

Comment: As far as I know, there is no law in Turkey which prohibits taking pictures of common things. I've taken photos of police there (with permission), and they even posed for me. This was last year though, but even now I don't see how this would bring any trouble (they might check your papers though).

Comment: The only restriction I have encountered as a fact was that tripods and flashes are forbidden inside Hagia Sophia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was there in the last weeks, i can say that in no moment has the policed ever cared about me taking photographs as a tourist. I even carry my tripod around and have not had the smallest problem. I am not a local, but i have stayed in the city for a month in this time period. I carry my big reflex camera with a Canon bag.

Answer (score 6):

Local here.

I'm not sure you *already* visited here or not since you said "one of the next weeks", but I will drop my two cent.

[NicolasZ's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78322/667) is quite accurate. If there is no "publication ban" (which is sometimes taken by government after some attacks for a *specific* area ) for the place you want to take photograph, you are always good to take it. Period. There is no law to prevent taking photos. Even if the police came near to you and ask what is going on, just explain them properly. Nothing happens.

> I'd obviously avoid sensitive targets (policemen, military personnel
>   and buildings)

Good because someone under arrested just because of try to catch a Pokemon with his mobile camera in front of a police station :) Of course he released after sometime but hey..

Source with Google Translate: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=tr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Ft24.com.tr%2Fhaber%2Feksi-sozluk-yazari-pokemon-go-yuzunden-gozaltina-alindim%2C349301&edit-text=

> But I like to take photos of common places, too, so while I'll
>   probably take photos of famous buildings I could take shots of common
>   houses, telephone boots, generic skyscraper...everything that can make
>   a good shot.

You will have *no* problem while you taking photos of the common places.